# Simple Passworded Page For Two People

Tags: php, html

i'm currently looking for simple passworded php page for two people, iv'e currently got this working for a single person and iv'e tried adapting it for 2 but i can't get it to work.

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($user == "admin"
&& $pass == "admin")
{
        include("page1.html");
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST))
    {?>

            <form method="POST" action="secure.php">
            User <input type="text" name="user"></input><br/>
            Pass <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
            </form>
    <?}
}
?>
```

I've tried two different ways both of which return errors.

```
if($user == "admin1"
    && $pass == "admin1")
    {
            include("page1.html");
    }
if($user == "admin2"
    && $pass == "admin2")
    {
            include("page2.html");
    }
```

and iv'e tried this way

```
if($user == "admin1, admin2"
    && $pass == "admin1, admin2")
    {
            include("page1.html, page2,html");
    }
```

I literally just need it for two logins and that's all, any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: `input` tags are self-closing, like this: `<input />`

Comment: *I've tried two different ways both of which return errors.* So you don't feel that you left something out from your question?

Comment: Isn't `<?}` supposed to be `<?php }`? Short tags are not always supported

Comment: Maybe https://3v4l.org/SBuZb is a better way? You should really provide the errors

Comment: @user3783243 I don't think the user and pass should be read literally from the question.

Comment: I don't see why the first way wouldn't work. What are the errors? (The second way definitely won't work.)

Comment: Comments aren't being answered, I have to wonder why. Plus, your code failed in too many ways. I've no idea why you'd want to use something as unsafe as that anyway. Unless this is homework/educational purposes. Someone could easily access those included files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to move where you check for whether `$_POST` is set, and `input` tags are self-closing, like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if ($user === "admin" && $pass === "admin")
    {
            include("page1.html");
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
            <form method="POST" action="secure.php">
            User <input type="text" name="user" /><br/>
            Pass <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
            </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Then this part needs an `else if` clause:

```
<?php
if ($user === "admin1" && $pass === "admin1")
{
        include("page1.html");
}
else if ($user === "admin2" && $pass === "admin2")
{
        include("page2.html");
}
?>
```

Also, it's good practice not to mix `<?php` tags and short open tags (`<?`) in your codebase.

Comment: Strict comparison on strings in $_POST data. Never seen that before. $_POST (and GET) is always strings. No need to be strict as I see it

Comment: Hi Matt, I believe `isset($_POST)` will always be true. PHP always sets the `$_POST` superglobal even if the request is not a post request, and `isset` only returns false for undefined or `null`, not for empty arrays.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, you're right, it should be `isset($_POST['submit'])` or `empty($_POST)`. I did know this already honestly ; ) thanks

Comment: You're welcome, and no offense intended. I just always try to support things I say on here, not necessarily just for the benefit of the person who posted the thing I'm commenting on

Comment: @Andreas It's just the way I code, I like to use strict whenever possible, however, it's more performant : )

Comment: @Don'tPanic no offence was taken, it was a valid and useful thing to point out!

Answer (score 1):

### Proper Account Storage

I would create an array of users (Similar to that which you would store in a database...), then check against this array when people log in.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {

    $users = [
        [
            "username" => "admin",
            "password" => "admin",
            "page" => "page1.html"
        ],
        [
            "username" => "admin2",
            "password" => "admin2",
            "page" => "page2.html"
        ]
    ];

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    //userid is the key of the user in your array
    $userid = array_search($user, array_column($users, 'username'));

    //if userid is false, that means the username doesn't exist
    if($userid !== false) {

        //assign this variable to the array of the user that is logging in
        $usr = $users[$userid];

        //check if users entered password is correct
        if($usr['password'] == $pass) {

            //display page if correct
            include($usr['page']);

            //kill the page if login successful, this way the form at the bottom does not show.
            //if nothing has been POSTed, or if the username/password are wrong, the form at the bottom will show
            die();
        }
    }

}

//this will always run if anything above fails
?>
    <form method="POST" action="secure.php">
        User <input type="text" name="user"/><br/>
        Pass <input type="password" name="pass"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
<?
```

This sets you up a much stronger system for logins, for the following reasons:

- Easily add new accounts without changing your if/else statements
- Easily convert into a database solution
- Fully dynamic, works with any amounts of logins

---

### Password Security

I don't know the security concerns of your application at all, but it's generally not recommended to store any password as plaintext. If anyone somehow gains access to read your PHP file, all of your accounts are now in danger.

There is a pretty simple solution here, simply store the passwords as a hash instead of plaintext. This has a few benefits:

- Secures your accounts, even if someone has direct access to read the file
- If done correctly, even *you* shouldn't know the passwords of any of your users
- Is extremely easy to implement

Now, normally you would use some sort of database for this, but you can do it straight into the code that I gave you earlier as well.

Let's say that I (GrumpyCrouton) want to use your application, so you send me to a password hash generator website like [this one](https://php-password-hash-online-tool.herokuapp.com/password_hash), or [this one](https://bcrypt-generator.com/) (There are a lot of these sites). (You can also make a page to generate them yourself, using `password_hash()`), and then send you the details for my login.

You would then create a new array entry with those details:

```
[
    "username" => "grumpycrouton",

    //remember to use single quotes for this, because if you use double quotes you will get a syntax/undefined error.
    "password" => '$2y$12$oHmy8gPNfcQ5j82lZCGA5uL8m0glyk/Imu1LhVhrPlAiLHzxjM0qW',
    "page" => "grumpycrouton.html"
]
```

Now, you'll have to modify your structure a bit for this to work, but it's a simple change.

Just change this line:

```
if($usr['password'] == $pass) {
```

To:

```
if(password_verify($pass, $usr['password'])) {
```

---

References:

- [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
- [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
- [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)
- [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)